# Is it possible to add a form to jquerymobile dialogs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-mobile, dialog

I have a form in my app where users can edit their settings. For some of the preferences, I would like to open a dialog containing a drop down menu allowing user to pick an option and have it saved through ajax. Is it possible with jquery mobile ?

Comment: It is just JavaScript and CSS so the most basic answer to your question is, yes, it is possible.  Maybe you'll want to expound on your question a bit?  Have you tried something and it isn't working?  Have you read the docs? etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is even shown in their examples. I would suggest you look at the [Popup](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/index.html) features of 1.2.0, they might work better for this type of quick change.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/BrsR2/

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Test PopUp</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup">Open Popup</a>
        <div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
            <form>
                <div style="padding:10px 20px; width: 440px">
                    <h3>Please sign in</h3>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="un">Username:</label>
                        <input placeholder="username" id="un" value="" name="user">
                        <label for="pw">Password:</label>
    <input id="pw" type="password" placeholder="password" value="" name="pass">
                    </div>
                    <div data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-icon="" data-iconpos="" data-theme="b" aria-disabled="false">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
             <label for="input"> Fieldname </label>
             <input type="text" id="input" value="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```